Power surge turns off entire house
Overhead light was being replaced in a hallway. There was two bar, wires, black, and white that immediately was exposed and cut all power circuit through the house. Go to breaker turn back on everything turn on, except for where that light was exposed with the wires room and appliance and kitchen and area, and another Part of the house, leads me to believe that the installing of the electricity system was improperly installed certain parts of the house immediately came on after the breaker was switched back now that same light overhead comes on when it wants to come on and let’s the other connections throughout the house that it is connected to come on when they come, but I don’t nowhere tell me to light fixture line wires need to be cut every thinking that the ball wire needs to be taken out to show me where it actually is connected to Wyatt connected to several different types of power throughout the house not just in one single house

Could you break this up into sentences and paragraphs? It's hard to read as it stands..

Also reread and revise for clarity. The phrase "was two bar, wires, black..." confounds me.

My apologies. let me fix my question.

A ceiling light was being removed . The black and the white wire was exposed to contact. Which made the whole breaker go off

So my question is do I replace bare wiring in the wall because now I I switched it on the breaker, but now it, the power comes on and goes off when it wants to

fix your question (above) don't add to/change it in the comments. It is very hard to discern what you are saying.

@Brittney this site is not a forum ... it is a Q&A site ... the entirety of your question belongs in the question section ... comments are not part of the question

Please read your question as if you've never seen it before, and you'll understand why we're all unable to understood the situation you're describing.  As it's currently written, we can't offer any advice other than to hire an electrician, but even if you do that you're going to have to explain the problem much more clearly.

It sounds like you had a short circuit at the light being replaced caused by some bare wires in the wiring in the wall.  The short circuit caused either the main breaker or many other circuit breakers throughout the house to blow. Then, when you turned the main breaker or other breakers back on, the circuit with the light on it started behaving strangely, with the power coming on and off at random.
All three of these -- the bare wires, the multiple circuit breakers blowing, and the circuit now randomly turning on and off -- sound like serious problems.
If you can, you should shut off the breaker for the circuit that is behaving strangely.  It's better if the power to that circuit is completely shut off.
Then, hire an electrician to come and inspect the problem.  This sounds like a complicated and dangerous situation, and you should not try fixing it yourself.
